# A formal synonym/expression for "saying that"

Tags: phrases, expressions, formality, expression-choice

I need a more formal expression for "saying that" here.  I couldn't find another formal  expression

> **Saying that** rape culture is an environment where emotional and physical violence against women is the norm is, in a way, normalizing and excusing sexist behaviors and beliefs.

Comment: I suppose that replacing the participle with the infinitive might satisfy: "To say that..." But I'm not sure that has exactly the same nuance of meaning; it's more hypothetical.

Comment: 'Maintaining that' ... would possibly satisfy your tutor.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options for your consideration:

> **state** *verb*: 3rd person present: states; past tense: stated; past participle: stated; gerund or present participle: stating
>
> 1. express something definitely or clearly in speech or writing.
>
> **synonyms**: express, voice, utter, put into words, declare, affirm, assert; see, Google [**state**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=state+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

In your example: To state [or, Stating] that rape culture is an environment where emotional and physical violence against women is the norm is, in a way, normalizing and excusing sexist behaviors and beliefs.

> **assert** *verb*: gerund or present participle: asserting
>
> state a fact or belief confidently and forcefully.
>
> **synonyms**: declare, maintain, contend, argue, state; see, Google [**assert**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=asserting+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

In your example: To assert [or, Asserting ] that rape culture is an environment where emotional and physical violence against women is the norm is, in a way, normalizing and excusing sexist behaviors and beliefs.

> **characterize** *verb*: gerund or present participle: characterizing
>
> 1. describe the distinctive nature or features of.
>
> **synonyms**: distinguish, make distinctive, mark, typify; see, Google [**characterize**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=characterizing+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

In your example: To characterize [or, Characterizing ] rape culture as an environment where emotional and physical violence against women is the norm is, in a way, normalizing and excusing sexist behaviors and beliefs."

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing in the infinitive form:

> **To say** that rape culture is an environment where emotional and physical violence is the norm is, in a way, **to normalize and excuse** sexist behaviors and beliefs.

Comment: yes indeed, the second part would seem like a hypothesis rather than a fact.

Comment: May be i should just omit it (saying that) the sentence would be then             " rape culture is an environment, where emotional and physical violence against women is the norm and, where sexist behaviors and attitudes are normalized and excused."

Comment: No, that changed the meaning entirely. Then it would mean that YOU claim that there is a rape "culture". The "saying that..." or "maintaining that..." or "claming that..." keeps you as an observer/commentator, separate from the beliefs you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start the sentence differently by saying something like '*The statement that rape culture....* or '*To theorize that rape...*' or even '*The idea/belief that rape culture...*'